# React Redux sync action return error when giving plain object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, redux, frontend

I'm learning React/Redux.
I have an action file:

```
import { RESIZE } from './actionType';

export const setSize = msg => (dispatch) => { 
    dispatch({ type: RESIZE, size: msg }); 
};
```

If I use above action, it will fail updating the redux store. But if I do it like below, redux store will be updated successfully:

```
import { RESIZE } from './actionType';

export const setSize = msg => ({ type: RESIZE, size: msg });
```

Usage:

```
import XXX
const CustomComponent = () => {
    setSize('large');
    render(some html);
}
CustomComponent.propTypes = {
    setSize: PropTypes.func
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ ...state });
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { setSize })(CustomComponent);
```

In the first example, console keeps giving an error which is 'action must be a plain object. Use custom middleware for async actions'. I am using a plain object in action. Then what's the problem with my code. I have search similar posts but nothing is applicable to my problem.

Comment: Show us how do you use it in your app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that an action creator by default must only return a plain JavaScript object. In your first example you are actually returning a function which receives `dispatch` as an argument. In other words, `setSize` actually returns a function and not a plain JavaScript object.
This is not allowed and only works if you use some sort of middleware like `redux-thunk` or similar.

Reading throigh the `redux-thunk` [docs](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) may help clarify this for you.